# How to reshape dataframe with multiple levels

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I currently have a dataframe (df1) formatted as shown below:

| ID | F1_1 | F2_1r1 | F2_1r2 | F2_1r3 | F1_2 | F2_2r1 | F2_2r2 | F2_2r3 | F1_3 | F2_3r1 | F2_3r2 | F2_3r3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 25 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 25 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 40 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 25 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I would like to reformat it so that it is arranged as shown here in df2:

| ID | F1_value | R1 | R2 | R3 | F1_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 25 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 30 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 25 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 40 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 15 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 25 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of your data using `dput()` rather than tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty efficiently using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(df1)
df2 <- melt(df1, measure = patterns("^F1", "r1$", "r2$", "r3$"),
            value.name = c("F1_value", "R1", "R2", "R3"), variable.name = "F1_x")
```

Producing:

```
    ID F1_x F1_value R1 R2 R3
 1:  1    1       10  1  1  0
 2:  2    1       25  1  0  0
 3:  3    1       40  0  1  0
 4:  4    1       25  1  1  0
 5:  1    2       15  0  1  0
 6:  2    2       30  0  1  1
 7:  3    2       15  0  1  0
 8:  4    2       10  0  1  1
 9:  1    3       30  1  0  0
10:  2    3       25  1  0  1
11:  3    3       10  0  0  1
12:  4    3       30  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I modify your solution for the new set of column names and formatting that I edited in the post? I no longer have letters, but rather number values that correspond the same way.

Comment: Just need to edit the patterns and the names. No need for the recoding line anymore. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_longer()` but it is easier if you rename the variables first as below:

```
x <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:4, 
  A1 = c(10,25,40,25), 
  A1.1=c(1,1,0,1), 
  A1.2=c(1,0,1,1), 
  A1.3=c(0,0,0,0), 
  B1 = c(15,30,15,10), 
  B1.1=c(0,0,0,0), 
  B1.2=c(1,1,1,1), 
  B1.3=c(0,1,0,1), 
  C1 = c(30,25,10,30), 
  C1.1=c(1,1,0,1), 
  C1.2=c(0,0,0,0), 
  C1.3=c(0,1,1,0)
)

x %>% 
  rename("A1.0" = "A1", 
         "B1.0" = "B1", 
         "C1.0" = "C1") %>% 
  pivot_longer(`A1.0`:`C1.3`, 
               names_pattern=c("([A-C])\\d.(\\d)"), 
               names_to=c("A_C", ".value"), 
               names_prefix = "R") %>%
  rename("A1_C1_value" = "0", 
         "R1" = "1", 
         "R2" = "2", 
         "R3" = "3")

# # A tibble: 12 × 6
#      ID A_C   A1_C1_value    R1    R2    R3
#   <int> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 A              10     1     1     0
# 2     1 B              15     0     1     0
# 3     1 C              30     1     0     0
# 4     2 A              25     1     0     0
# 5     2 B              30     0     1     1
# 6     2 C              25     1     0     1
# 7     3 A              40     0     1     0
# 8     3 B              15     0     1     0
# 9     3 C              10     0     0     1
# 10     4 A              25     1     1     0
# 11     4 B              10     0     1     1
# 12     4 C              30     1     0     0**
```